# How can we use wildcard functionality in more than one columns in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I use wildcard functionality in more than one columns in SQL Server 2008?

below is my query

```
SELECT *
FROM sheet1
WHERE description like '%abc%'
```

If I fire the given then i'm able retrieve data in description columns whichever are in abc  but I'm not able to search same with other columns.
I want something like

```
SELECT *
FROM sheet1
WHERE description,data like '%abc%'
```

Comment: I gave you an answer on your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910523/how-to-use-description-like-abc-in-sql-server-2008/20911621#20911621 please do not repost identical questions. Edit the original.

Comment: You use `AND` for any additional conditions you wish to add. For additional information use google, or msdn, or check amazon for books on writing sql, or search for similar questions on this site, or take a class.

Comment: I have done research but didn't get appropriate output that's why I post it and thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM sheet1
WHERE
    [description] like '%abc%'
    AND [data] like '%abc%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add the predicate on each column.

```
SELECT * FROM sheet1 WHERE description like '%abc%' AND data like '%abc%'
```